# TCL, Regular Expression with ')', ']' or '}'

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying, in TCL, to write a regex to detect 0 or more characters ')', ']' or '}' in the end of a string.

Like the following, using **a**, **b** and **c** instead of **)**, **]** and **}**...

```
% regexp {[a]*$} "_______a" m
1
% put $m  ; # Prints affected portion
a
% regexp {[a]*$} "_______aaaa" m
1
% put $m
aaaa
% regexp {[ab]*$} "_______ababababab" m
1
% put $m
ababababab
% regexp {[abc]*$} "_______abcbabcaccc" m
1
% put $m
abcbabcaccc
%
```

I couldn't find how to escape the characters.

Thanks in advance.

Gmne

---

*Added...*

> Precede Them with \ , for example, \) .

Thanks *MRAB*. Thats work good on Linux!. 
But it seems not to be the same for Windows..

```
% ### Windows:
% regexp {[\)\]\}]+$} "_____)))"
0
% regexp {[\)]+$} "_____)))" m
1
% puts $m
)))
% regexp {[\)]+$} "_____)\\\\" m
1
% puts $m
)\\


% ### Linux
% regexp {[\)\]\}]+$} "_____)))" m
1
% puts $m
)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use english on StackOverflow.

Comment: Google translate (from Spanish): http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=es&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876272/tcl-expresion-regular-con-o&usg=ALkJrhi-6Qvn1dhelabR1oJpLHX_qOYwMg

Comment: Ok, practicing my old skills. Just hope I didn't change the meaning of something.

Comment: sorry. :-J . i will try to do that from now on

Comment: I just tried this on my machine, `regexp {[\)]+$} "_____)\\\\" m` on windows returns `0`, what version of Tcl are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Precede them with `\`, for example, `\)`.

Comment: +1: This is exactly correct in all three cases. If you were to only want one of them, you would not need to put the backslashed version inside square brackets either.